# How Encoding problems are solves in the web

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, web

I have developed web applications for 1 year where the environment is(apache,php,html5 and javascript).I didn't care before this time to encoding issues.It was like the magic.I merely set mysql connection in a configuration file to UTF-8 and forget.
But after my experience grew I faced cases where I need to fully understand how encoding issues are solved in this environment.When I get something,I miss the others.So I couldn't get the full picture.
To be clear:

- Javascript Strings are UTF-16
- HTTP transport encoding is arbitrary.
- PHP Strings are Binary.
- Mysql connection also is arbitrary.

How the conversion is done and what are the possible issues I need to care about.

Comment: Make everything UTF-8. [A good reading](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Comment: Take the above together with [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/), that should clear things up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue only really exists at the *boundary* between two systems. Within one system (PHP, a database, Javascript etc. individually) there are clear ways how to deal with encodings and there's usually little friction there. The issue typically is that a blob of binary data is transferred from one system to another, say PHP to the database, without *correctly specifying in the accompanying metadata what encoding that blob is in*.

Different interfaces between systems have different ways of specifying that required meta data. The interface between PHP and the database allows to specify a connection encoding, which makes the database "understand" what encoding is being used by PHP and what encoding it expects in return. Between the web server/PHP and the browser there are HTTP headers and/or HTML meta tags which allow this metadata to be specified.

One system always has to yield. Either one system is sending data in a specific encoding, telling the recipient what encoding that is and the recipient will have to deal with it; or the recipient can specify upfront what encoding it needs and the sender will have to convert it to that encoding before sending.

- between PHP and most databases, PHP specifies the encoding to be used and the database converts text on the fly to that encoding
- between web servers/PHP and browsers, the server/PHP declares what encoding the content it's sending is in and the browser has to deal with it
- the server also declares what encoding it expects if the browser is sending any data through the `accept-charset` attribute of forms, or the browser infers it from the content it received
- Javascript receives text after the browser has dealt with it, so it doesn't really care about encodings

Answer (score 5):

They are not arbitrary, they are what you tell them to be. So in general, you can make everything UTF-8, and you're fine.

Javascript strings are only UTF-16 internally. The JS files you send, can be UTF-8. If you tell your browser which encoding a response has, the browser will be able to convert to whatever encoding it needs. The trouble only starts when you specify a different encoding than you actually send.

Why UTF-8?

- Every ANSI encoding has problems specifying all characters (there's only room for 256 different characters).
- UTF-8 is usually the most compact unicode format, especially when you transport western languages.
- UTF-8 is the only unicode encoding that isn't affected by Byte Order Mark differences between Linux and Windows, although that is also something you don't usually have to worry about.

Recommended reading:
[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: I meant by arbitrary you can set to any value you prefer